# How to figure out the boundaries on Graph API's limit parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0,

```
Some edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.
```

A recent response for https://graph.facebook.com/20531316728/feed?limit=500&access_token=CAACE... is

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) The 'limit' parameter should not exceed 250",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

However (as documented) some endpoints allow `limit=500`. The response has error code `100` and error type `OAuthException` but the message tells a different story. What is a good way to detect that the HTTP 400 Bad Request response is because of the limit parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been raised to Facebook developer team. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/763425230375017/